# Variable number of records per page in Yii

Tags: yii, pagination

I'm trying to get variable number of records per page in Yii. The page size is dependent on the number of records that match a criteria, so It has to be changed on every AJAX request sent by Yii's pagination.

Here's a sketch of the exact problem:

Table Structure [pk, user_id, entry_date, entry_message]

The view has a CGridView with pagination enabled and pageSize set to 10. What I want to do is to show the entries from one date on one page. For example, page one should show the entries from today. Page two should show the entries from yesterday. So I presume that the limit and the offset should be variable, but I can't quiet understand how to change them.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain with some example?

Comment: we will help you if you insert your controler codes.